# SFML tcp server recieves messages with additionals

Tags: c++, tcp, server, sfml

I use example code of server from SFML2.3.1 package. If I send message from any other applications(TCP clients), I will get message with additionals like on this screen: http://s21.postimg.org/yh0r0c0cn/example.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're printing more bytes than you received. If you use TcpSocket's receive, it requires third parameter reference to size_t so you can tell how much data you got. check [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1TcpSocket.php#a90ce50811ea61d4f00efc62bb99ae1af)

Answer (score 0):

You're printing data you didn't receive. Log the number of bytes you received and you'll see that it's less than the number of bytes you printed.

Your code probably looks something like this:

```
int i = recv (sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
printf ("Got: %s\n", buf);
```

Notice that the value of `i` is not used? So how is `printf` supposed to know how many bytes to print?

Note that this is probably just the tip of the iceberg. TCP is not a message protocol, but you think that you are sending messages. This likely indicates the failure to actually design and implement a message protocol, a common mistake made by people who are not familiar with TCP. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. If you want a message protocol, you have to implement one on top.